# Cordova app freeze on iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm in a team and we are building an app with Cordova. The Android version works well, but the iOS version has a strange behaviour... it randomly freezes. There is no error, we didn't find no way to trace something strange. Sometimes the app starts and works well, sometimes (the same build) it freezes on splashscreen (or after the splascreen has gone).
If we watch the "broken" app with inspector, we don't see nothing...
We also tried to remove all plugins, but we have the same "error".
The app is based on Onsen and Angular.

Thanks for every helping tip..

Comment: What is the definition of freezing? You cant scroll it ?
Check if all the ajax requests are done. 
Also if it is not scrolling then it is possible that there is some overflow: hidden property on some of the main containers.

Comment: The app is blocked. If you touch the screen (there is a menu), there is no response, nor scrolling.

Comment: what version of cordova-ios platform are you building against?

Comment: I had the 4.0.1 version of Cordova, now I have the 4.1.0 and it seems to work!

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing intermittent freeze on app startup with cordova-ios@4.0.1 but upgrading to cordova-ios@4.1.0 resolved the issue.

See here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10530

Comment: @DaveAlden Can you please specify how to upgrade cordova-ios in detail? I don't really want to do a trial and error just before the release. I am facing the same problem and that too only on ios

Comment: @imsheth just remove and re-add the platform: `cordova platform rm ios && cordova platform add ios`. Current default is cordova-ios@4.1.1

Comment: @DaveAlden : will try that out !